# Javascript Checkbox Ticked on Load Error

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a .cshtml page that I'm going to set up with several checkboxes.

The checkboxes should be checked/unchecked depending on the values of several variables passed into the view using the TempData.

I've set up the code as follows:

```
<script>

    @if (TempData["enabled"] == "True") {
       var eCheckBox = document.getElementById(eCheck);
       eCheckBox.checked = true;

    }

</script>

<h2>Update @TempData["fullName"]</h2>

<input type="checkbox" name="enabledCheckbox" value="Enabled" id="eCheck"/>Enabled<br/>
```

But the line

```
eCheckBox.checked = true;
```

produces the error 'identifier expected;checked is a keyword'. Is there something obvious I'm missing? Making a checkbox ticked on load seems like it should be simple to do.

EDIT: I tried to correct the code as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="enabledCheckbox" value="Enabled" id="eCheck" onload="checkTrue()"/>Enabled<br/>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkTrue() {
        alert("Here!");


        if (TempData["enabled"] == "True") {
            document.querySelector('[name=enabledCheckbox]').checked = true;
        }
    }

</script>
```

It doesn't look as though the code is hitting the function at all, as no alert fires.

Comment: In your edited code you put the logic inside a function, does the function get called?  Maybe wrap it in a Document.Ready block or just put in checkTrue() somewhere in the script tags?

Answer (score 1):

You miss to retrieve your HTML element correctly through JS. Just use this:

```
document.querySelector('[name=enabledCheckbox]').checked = true;
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't seem to be working. I put it in a function and tried to call it onload with an alert for debug purposes, but the function is not being called at all.

Comment: the input element doesn't have an `onload` event, that's why it is not called. 
Keep the code as you have and invoke the function inside the script, 
`checkTrue();`